# How to read the message of a notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm making an application and I would like it to read the notification message and search for words within the message (convert notification to string, regex to search). I just started reading about the NotificationListenerService but seems like a lot of work to just grab the message...

Is there a short code I can implement to add the latest notification message to a string?

Comment: This page helped me somewhat understand. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html/comment-page-1/#comment-8063 however I'm not sure how k9 mailer is sending the body of the email in the notification..  I tried bigtext and other things with no luck.